# CakePHP removing special characters from this->params

Tags: cakephp-1.2, cakephp

I am using jQuery to pass data to the following URL in my cakephp 1.2 app:

```
$("#test").load("http://domain.com/controller/action/productID:2001642/questionID:2501322/value:C%2B%2B/questionType:3", function({
  $("#test").fadeOut(3000);
});
```

In the controller when I

```
debug($this->params['named']);
```

it returns

```
Array
(
    [productID] => 2001642
    [questionID] => 2501322
    [value] => C  
    [questionType] => 3
)
```

The URL part of $this displays

```
[url] => Array
                (
                    [url] => deu/productanswers/updateoredit/productID:2001642/questionID:2501322/value:C  /questionType:3
                )
```

so that somewhere along the line the C++ or C%2B%2B is getting squished.

Does anyone have a solution or workaround please?

Cheers,
Taff

Answer (score 0):

Although I would be very interested in a cakephp solution, I resorted to using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Definitely not a sexy solution

```
$tmp1 = explode('value:',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$tmp2 = explode('/',$tmp1[1]); 
$prod=$this->params['named']['productID'];
$ques=$this->params['named']['questionID'];     
$value=urldecode($tmp2[0]);
```

Hope this helps someone in the future...